# Submit Application not possible

Tags: java, ios, xcode, app-store, submit

I tried very hard the last two days to submit an update of our App to Apple directly out of XCode. The archive is always verified, but the submit process is stopped then with an error-message in XCode Organiser

```
an error occoured uploading to the iTunes Store
```

I opened the Console Application on the specific Mac and there is an error telling me something about a wrong java-version:

```
05.04.12 11:29:52,557 Xcode:  Error:
Java 1.5, 1.6, or 1.7 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please     upgrade.
05.04.12 11:29:52,558 Xcode:  Out:
05.04.12 11:31:16,776 Xcode:  Error:
05.04.12 11:31:16,777 Xcode:  Out:
```

I couldn't believe this should be the problem, cause two days before, i could submit an app binary to the store on this Mac without a problem.

On terminal launching `java -version` outputs:

```
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-413-11M3623)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-413, mixed mode)
```

I thing i remember that there's been an JAVA Update by Apple in the last days.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: Everybody who installed the Java update has the same problem ;-) https://devforums.apple.com/message/643089#643089 Solution included

Comment: Thanks! The Link helped a lot! Now it works. So this is a Bug apple needs to fix real quick!

Comment: the fix just arrived via software update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug! After installation of the latest JAVA Update by Apple via Apple Software Updater, it is not possible to upload binarys to the Store. There is a workaround by entering the following commands in termin to create symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5

sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

There is no need for a restart of Xcode after that or a restart of the whole Mac. Right after setting the symlinks you can upload binarys to the Store and also the Application Loader is working as supposed to.

Comment: This saved me! Thank you so much.  I couldn't, for the life of me, figure out why this wasn't working!

Comment: Apple released the Update, so if you still have the problem, check if your Mac OS X is uup to Date.

Answer (score 2):

The update `Java for OS X 2012-002` (released today) fixed the problem.

Before the update, the symlinks are missing:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
1.6     1.6.0       A       Current     CurrentJDK
```

after the update:

```
$ ls /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
1.4     1.4.2       1.5     1.5.0       1.6     1.6.0       A       Current     CurrentJDK
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Java 1.7 broke the uploader AGAIN. Im using;

```
OSX 10.7.4
Xcode 4.4.1
```

And getting the same error. I reported it as a bug on ADC and it was acknowledged as such. Two ways to fix:

1. In light of recent security issues with 1.7 remove that jvm from your system (uninstall) and fall back to Apples latest 1.6.35 patch.
2. If you require 1.7 then you can temporarily turn it off while you upload then re-enable (or not) :) by doing the following: Application > Utilities > Java Preferences and uncheck Oracle Ver of Java (1.7.0_04).