# Java 2012-006 update broke xCode Uploading

Tags: java, xcode, app-store

This is related to this question
[Submit Application not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026248/submit-application-not-possible)

However after the most recent java update from apple (that removed the web plugin) oracle immediatley issued an update for java 7

Now xcode can't upload anymore "An error occurred uploading to the iTunes Store" and the old fix doesn't work. Is Java 1.6 gone? Or do we need to do something else?

Comment: Seems like Xcode 4.5.1 fixes the Issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in terminal

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions  
open .
```

Then copy out the Current and CurrentJDK folders to the desktop or other location and

```
rm Current*  
ln -s 1.6.0/ Current  
ln -s 1.6.0/ CurrentJDK
```

This fixes the upload issue then when you are done in Terminal

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
rm Current*
open .
```

Then copy the originals back from the desktop and you Java will be working again.

Comment: For future reference: "Current" symlinks to "A" in that Versions folder. And "CurrentJDK" symlinks to "/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents"

Answer (score 9):

The previous answers are ok if you have an old copy of Java. An easy fix (that will break Java, and then you can revert it back) is to temporarily remove/backup the two symlinks.

1. cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
2. sudo mv Current Current.bak
3. sudo mv CurrentJDK CurrentJDK.bak
4. Upload your binary
5. sudo mv Current.bak Current
6. sudo mv CurrentJDK.bak CurrentJDK

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to anyone who doesn't have any other versions of Java linked, I found simply deleting the Current and CurrentJDK files worked. There were no issues noted in /var/log/system.log , which leads me to believe Xcode simply either skips the script requiring Java, or found a 1.6 version of Java by itself.

Same steps as Gary Rudolph described:

cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

```
sudo mv Current Current.bak
sudo mv CurrentJDK.bak CurrentJDK.bak
```

Upload your binary

```
sudo mv Current.bak Current
sudo mv CurrentJDK.bak CurrentJDK
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the instructions found at this website

http://creativepark.net/1146

```
rm Current*
ln -s 1.6.0/ Current
ln -s 1.6.0/ CurrentJDK
```

However this seems to have broken java :( atleast my upload worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use xcode 4.6 Organizer to submit your archive. 
And you do not need to do anything with Java on your Mountain Lion