# Cannot upload my app to iTunes from XCode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I've seen a lot of questions with this error type, but solution of them wasn't helpful. I try to upload update for my app to iTunes, but xCode gives me an error with this text: "An error occured uploading to the iTunes Store". XCode with latest version 4.5.1.
I think this problem began after last October Java update 2012-006. I've tried to do this:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

but no result. Same error again and again. 
Who had the same problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after I've searched better, I found solution that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965533/902424)

Hope it will help someone