# Uploading IOS app to app store. Seems to freeze and internet stop working

Tags: ios, xcode, upload

In Xcode i have have created an archive of the app. Verified it no problem. then when i click Distribute i get as far as "Your application is being uploaded" and shows the progress bar.
The bar never moves and after a few minutes my internet breaks. i need to restart my router to get the internet back.

one of the times i received this error "SSL error occured and a secure connection to the server cannot be made"

Anyone ever experienced this or have an idea of whats happening?

Thanks

Comment: This exact thing happened to me yesterday and I... I couldn't believe it - so I tested it 5-6 times... It reproduced with 100% reliability - my router would die during the .ipa upload... My router has never freezed before that, it's a very reliable machine. What I noticed after many trials was - the closer the upload is to a system (my macbook) restart, the further it goes as progress. So after a few restarts I managed to uploaded before it kills my network. The weirdest problem I had in some time, definitely.

Comment: This is still a problem. I believe it has to do with network security settings. On my office network the uploads are always permanently stuck at 0%. When I tether to my iPhone (Verizon) or upload from home it always works immediately. I think Apple is using an unusual port that raises security concerns. It's pretty amazing that they still haven't addressed it. I can easily upload to the Google Play Store from my office network with no issues.

Answer (score 13):

**I also faced this problem: "*your application is being uploaded stuck*"**

**My ANSWER IS:**

***Either just delete your derived data from organizer or Instead of uploading via Xcode, try via it using Application Loader***.

I choosed via Appplication Loader and Steps to do that are:

**Step1:** Make .ipa file via Ad-Hoc Deployment by click Distribution button.

**Step2:** Find from menu bar of Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader.

**Step3:** Then upload it that .ipa file in Application Loader.

**

### OR ANOTHER SOLUTION

**

**For uploading it via XCode:**

**Step1:** Firstly Validate your archive file by clicking on validation button of Organiser.

**Step2:** Then Upload it to App Store via Oraganiser.*This way you can also solve this problem as well*

**THIS IS MY ANSWER . HAPPY TO HELP :):)**

Comment: none of working.I dont have any firewall or built-in firewall active.

Answer (score 3):

apple uses java ?
my mac does not have problem for internet.any application can download/upload.
except xcode's organizer's distribute or application loader blocks whole internet and modem stops working for a temporal time.

it is obvious not a mac problem. but apple's uploading system strategy seems not good.
they gotto fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard of some users having issues if they're running old versions of Java.  If you can't update, or if updating doesn't fix it, you can try:

```
sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5

sudo ln -s CurrentJDK /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0
```

(other similar workarounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026248/submit-application-not-possible).)

It could also be an Internet connectivity issue.

Either way, you can also try [uploading your app using Application Loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924085/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-without-xcode).

Comment: My app is just over 20mb, i will give the application loader a go.

Comment: @johnnym65 Just found a known issue about Java too, check that out.  20MB should be fine though.

Comment: The application loader ask's you to choose a file to upload. What file should i choose? do i need to export something within xcode

Comment: You need to give it the IPA file.  You can use the Terminal command at the top of that answer, or in Xcode Window -> Organizer -> Archives -> Right-click your Archive -> Show in Finder

Comment: hey, when i right click the archive and choose "show in finder" it then shows me a Xcode Archive file rather than IPA file. I also followed the terminal command to build it into a .app file.but the next command to package it as a IPA is a tad confusing!

Comment: could you please elaborate Rohan? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- I updated my old Java version (from 21 to 51). Is still freezing my Internet.
- I validated my archive with Organizer. Is still freezing my Internet.
- I tried to upload an IPA with Application Loader. Is still freezing my Internet.
- I deleted all my old archives in Organizer. Is still freezing my Internet.

Finally I connected my Mac to Internet through my iPhone's Internet. In resume I connected my Mac to Internet with another provider. **This solved my problem**

Sounds like my land ADSL provider have some problem with the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

It will be to do with your firewall on your mac, it may be blocking java all together. Go to settings, security and privacy and then firewall. Once on there go to fire wall options and then there should be an option to allow java to pass through the firewall. 
Hope that helps, did with me :)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above suggestions work for me. Likely the real cause is physical and related how Application Loader is using the internet. I have ADSL2 connection with a Netgear modem/router assigning each device at home a fixed IP address according to the mac address of the network interface of each device. I had noticed that when Application Loader is uploading, my Windows PC could not connect to the internet. However, if in Mac mini I use Safari doing various things like watching video, my Windows PC can access internet.

Even stranger, when Application Loader is uploading, the modem/router could easily lost connection to the internet, as I could see from the LED lights of the modem. The connection is lost randomly at any progress of uploading the 20 MB file.

So I had turned off Windows PCs, iPads, iPhones and Android device at home, so Mac mini is the only device using the Internet, the Application Loading has finally been able to upload the app successfully in one go.

My guess is, my home phone line has some noise, and Application Loader is using the internet aggressively particularly the up link, so stressing out the modem, then causing other devices like my Windows PC lost connection, not even able to resolve host. When Safari is uploading video to App Store, no problem.

So my working solution is to make Mac be the only device using the Internet, given that the internet connection is already in poor condition with noise, near the edge of losing connection.

Answer (score 0):

It's very old issue, but in case any of you is still looking for a solution, I stopped using Xcode to upload my apps to the app store. Instead I'm using Transporter (by Apple) and it seems to fix the freezing