# "Your application is being uploaded" forever to iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

I try to upload my updated version for my app and everything seems all right, but I stay in Your application is being uploaded screen more than hour. I already create a new version on iTunes Connect and display "Waiting For Upload" in there. And also my app is not that big file and only updated version.

Could any one tell me what happened in there and how to fix it?

Comment: FIND MY ANSWER: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17211221/1092219 HAPPY TO HELP :) :)

Comment: I experience this same problem at random times, one minutes it works, the next it doesn't. What a pain.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are 2 steps for this:
1. **Make .ipa file** (select 'Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment by click Distribue... button') 
2. **Upload in Application Loader** (Find from menu bar of Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Application Loader)

Answer (score 9):

Instead of trying to upload via Xcode, try using Application Loader. Export the archive as an .ipa file, using the App Store distribution profile. Launch Application Loader by choosing Xcode → Open Developer Tool → Application Loader, and hand it the .ipa file.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced same problem and I found it was network issue at my office. When I tried to upload at home, it worked without any delay. So, I assumed there is any specific port used by apple uploader that was blocked at the office.

Answer (score 0):

I waited about an hour, I re-archived my app on organizer and then my submit was fine