# IOS 7 - Xcode5 Organiser upload issue

Tags: ios, xcode, upload, in-app-purchase

I done some test on the In App Purchase app and everything goes well. Now I want to upload a simple In App Purchase Non-consumable content to test the download handling. I had done everything and validate with Xcode 5 Organiser and did not get any error. When I distribute it to the server, The progress stop at "Your content is being uploaded". The progress bar did not move at all. And my content is only 130k, just an jpg image.

Do anyone have any suggestion or solution on this?

Comment: Definitely give apple developer support a call.. could be an issue on there end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this solution:

> I've heard of some users having issues if they're running old versions
>   of Java. If you can't update, or if updating doesn't fix it, you can
>   try:
>
> sudo ln -s CurrentJDK
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5
>
> sudo ln -s CurrentJDK
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0 (other
>   similar workarounds here.)
>
> It could also be an Internet connectivity issue.

check out more solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247449/uploading-ios-app-to-app-store-seems-to-freeze-and-internet-stop-working?rq=1).